# How to do File upload validation Server side without refreshing the Page?

Tags: php, validation, upload

I have created a script to Upload a file using PHP. I have also added file validation checking for File size & File type. But the scenario here is, the Form contain 10-12 Text boxes & a File upload box. So whenever someone fill the complete form & submit and they get File upload validation error, they get back to the Form with the validation error message. But the form gets empty as obviously it get posted on server side.
Is there any way to do the file upload validation without reloading/refreshing the page ?

Comment: I've done it once with an iFrame. You have a form target the iFrame, so it the processing happens there, not on the current page. I don't remember the entire details. [Google it](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/11/ajax-style-file-uploading-using-hidden-iframe.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend this plugin for file uploads. http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

It will allow you to verify the file, and if theres an error you can use json to determine whether the file is valid or not. I use it in all my projects, it's fantastic.

EDIT: Also it allows you to submit files without page refresh, which is the most important part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax:

1) when submit an ajax synchrounous call send the form content to the php server page
2) the php page validates the input
3) if return is "false" (error in validation) the javascript that executed the call sympli insert into the html of the page a proper message. The form stands filled in with the values of the user

Answer (score 0):

You can use  $_POST array  for the posted values from the form . You should have write form method as POST

Also the same way you can ajax form this will not loose any of your data and page will not refresh as well